# Merging two matrices of different sizes

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two symmetrical correlation matrices, of which one represents a subset of the other. I want to merge both matrices into long format, to later use this for x,y plots. Here is a small example.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

dist1 <- matrix(runif(16),4,4)
dist2 <- matrix(runif(9),3,3)
rownames(dist1) <- colnames(dist1) <- paste0("A",1:4)
rownames(dist2) <- colnames(dist2) <- paste0("A",1:3)

m1 <- melt(dist1)
m2 <- melt(dist2)

final <- merge(m1,m2, by=c("X1","X2"))
ggplot(final, aes(value.x,value.y)) + geom_point()
```

This is all fine. `final` contains as much x1,x2 pairs as found in the smaller matrix `m2`.
However in my real life example, things are looking differently:

```
dim(m1) # the large matrix
[1] 14845516     3
dim(m2) # the small matrix
[1] 574564    3
dim(final) # the merged product
[1] 286894    4
```

It is suspicious that `final`'s pairs represent slightly more than the half of the pairs in `m2` (and the difference is pretty close but not equal to the number of diagonal cells in `m2`), so maybe `merge()` did find only one triangle.But my assumption right now is that m2 is not a subset of m1 (although it should be). So, my questions are:

How can i check if all the pairs in m2[,1:2] appears also in m1[,1:2]?

Is there a better option to create a merged dataframe from m1 and m2 that contains every X1,X2-pair that is included in both matrices? Optimally, only unique pairs, e.g. from A1,A2 and A2, A1, only one pair gets selected.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is a better approach that should generalise to your larger set, although without a direct test it's hard to tell.  I'm not sure what your `X1` and `X2` variables are, but this ought to work.  The number of rows of your merged result should be equal to the number of rows of `m2` (the smaller matrix) here.

I changed your first line to `library(reshape2)`, which generates along with the rest of your code these two objects:

```
> m1
   Var1 Var2      value
1    A1   A1 0.50120206
2    A2   A1 0.07627305
3    A3   A1 0.73757589
4    A4   A1 0.24007736
5    A1   A2 0.93485899
6    A2   A2 0.67076761
7    A3   A2 0.92666447
8    A4   A2 0.79405152
9    A1   A3 0.33120170
10   A2   A3 0.48999764
11   A3   A3 0.86967692
12   A4   A3 0.01966199
13   A1   A4 0.03986184
14   A2   A4 0.50578328
15   A3   A4 0.30689141
16   A4   A4 0.54859405
> m2
  Var1 Var2      value
1   A1   A1 0.56995004
2   A2   A1 0.81317914
3   A3   A1 0.51047761
4   A1   A2 0.16949663
5   A2   A2 0.21790332
6   A3   A2 0.75785648
7   A1   A3 0.75591111
8   A2   A3 0.92541073
9   A3   A3 0.07877851
```

To merge these, use a join operation from the **dplyr** package, e.g.

```
> final <- dplyr::full_join(m1, m2, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
Warning messages:
1: In outer_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
2: In outer_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

> final
   Var1 Var2    value.x    value.y
1    A1   A1 0.50120206 0.56995004
2    A2   A1 0.07627305 0.81317914
3    A3   A1 0.73757589 0.51047761
4    A4   A1 0.24007736         NA
5    A1   A2 0.93485899 0.16949663
6    A2   A2 0.67076761 0.21790332
7    A3   A2 0.92666447 0.75785648
8    A4   A2 0.79405152         NA
9    A1   A3 0.33120170 0.75591111
10   A2   A3 0.48999764 0.92541073
11   A3   A3 0.86967692 0.07877851
12   A4   A3 0.01966199         NA
13   A1   A4 0.03986184         NA
14   A2   A4 0.50578328         NA
15   A3   A4 0.30689141         NA
16   A4   A4 0.54859405         NA
```

(Don't worry about the warnings here.)

The row, column label pairs in your smaller object `m2` will always be unique, if you want just the items in the smaller matrix, then you can use `right_join()`, e.g:

```
> dplyr::right_join(m1, m2, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
  Var1 Var2    value.x    value.y
1   A1   A1 0.50120206 0.56995004
2   A2   A1 0.07627305 0.81317914
3   A3   A1 0.73757589 0.51047761
4   A1   A2 0.93485899 0.16949663
5   A2   A2 0.67076761 0.21790332
6   A3   A2 0.92666447 0.75785648
7   A1   A3 0.33120170 0.75591111
8   A2   A3 0.48999764 0.92541073
9   A3   A3 0.86967692 0.07877851
Warning messages:
1: In right_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
2: In right_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Comment: I get the same results using the original code using `melt`. The only difference here is that the sorting of levels in `Var1` and `Var2` differs. So I see no real superiority using **dplyr** here.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if all the pairs in m2[,1:2] appear in m1[,1:2] using `intersect()` function from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dim(intersect(m2[,1:2],m1[1:2]))
[1] 9 2
dim(m2[,1:2])
[1] 9 2
```

Also, try to check if your variables are coded as factors. If so, you can get strange results if you merge data frames on those variables. It is better to convert them to characters.

As for optimal ways to merge data frames, `merge` from base R, as well as `inner_join` from `dplyr` and joins from `data.table` packages all should be good enough in handling that task. `data.table` would probably be the quickest.

And if you want only unique pairs, you should run `unique(m1[,1:2])` before doing the merge.

Comment: I agree that this helps solving the problem as it helps you finding out why (!) your merge result is not as expected. Yet, using `unique(m1[, 1:2])` does not help to get rid of the duplicate entries such as `A1, A2` and `A2, A1`.